# Does WCF have performance issues compared to named pipes and remoting?

Tags: c#, wcf, performance

I'm just starting WCF...but will this slow down interprocess communication further compared to the old remoting,Tcp sockets or Named Pipes?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the performance will not be slow.  WCF has transports based on TCP and [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx).  In other words, the programming model (WCF) is independent of the transport.  This is one of the foundational principles of WCF.

WCF can and will use the optimal data transmission mechanism, and you'll get good performance.  You should benchmark your scenario, but in most cases, the cost of the data transmission is small in comparison to the cost of the operation *after* the transmission.

Also, [here is a document comparing the performance of WCF with alternatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx), an analysis produced by Microsoft.