# How about WCF for large number of clients and large amounts of data?

Tags: c#, wcf, performance

Does anyone have statistics of using WCF with 20000 clients?

Just don't know it's performance of loading 20000+ clients, anyone can give me a real data about this?

And also, for each client, we will transfer data from several Kb to 100MB, does it suitable for WCF to finish this in a good performance?

And also, is there any messaging platform good enough for us to use with low cost in money?

Just need purely .net platform.

Would anyone have some insights on this?

Thx very much.

Comment: It depends on multiple factors: session or not, security, ... Could you precise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/859301/55209

Comment: @lnu No security or encryption required and for the session , it's 2 or 3 times a day or on demand

Comment: @Artem Koshelev   thx for help, think that it's useful.

Comment: Seems that with your requirements you won't have any performance problems. Look also at the configuration of your service:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061(v=bts.10).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it yourself by using the [WCF Load Test](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/).

> This tool takes a WCF trace file and a WCF client proxy, or a WCF interface contract, and generates a C# unit test that replays the same sequence of calls found in the trace file. The unit test can then be used to load-test the target.

Here's a [really good walkthrough in using the WCF Load Test](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/12/03/generating-load-tests-for-wcf-services-with-the-wcf-load-test-tool.aspx). The [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221973/load-testing-wcf-service-hosted-on-iis) might also help you.